# Pythonic list slicing with variable step size?

Tags: python, list, indexing

To frame the question, let's assume I've got the following list in Python, where X is some arbitrarily large natural number:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ... X]
```

And I want to slice it such that I take the first, second, third, fifth, eighth, etc. elements of the list, abiding by the Fibonacci sequence. E.g. an operation akin to:

```
l_prime = [l[0], l[1], l[2], l[4], l[7], l[11], ...]
```

I'm comfortable with Python indexing notation, of `l[start:end:step_size]`, and I'm wondering if there's a way to index Python lists within this notational paradigm with a step size that varies after each index is added to my new sliced list. Or, would I need to use some other technique to solve the prior problem I posed?

Comment: you say you want to slice the list, but then you say you want to take the `first, second, third, fifth, eighth, etc. elements of the list`, slice generally takes more than one element at a time, but if you want to take one element, you can just use indexes, can you clarify on this

Comment: Yes - sorry if I was unclear! I'd like to slice `l` such that the resulting sliced list contains the first, second, third... elements. E.g. something akin to the following: ```l_prime = [l[0], l[1], l[2], l[4], l[7] ... ]```.

Comment: Can you add your example slices in the question just to be more clear?

Comment: Yup! I'll edit that right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use numpy this is really easy.

```
l = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, ..., X])
fibs = np.array([0, 1, 2, 4, 7])
print(l[fibs])
```

Comment: This is why I love NumPy - though I presume there isn't an equivalent for standard Python lists?

Comment: You will have to hardcode the indices, imagine you want to get the first 50 elements

Comment: @fafl no need, you can compute fibs array from a function

Comment: @zen_of_python AFAIK no its not possible with standard lists

Answer (score 2):

If you want to retrieve multiple elements from the list you can use the function `itemgetter()`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
ind = [0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 7] 

itemgetter(*ind)(lst)
# (1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first write a generator that gives you the fibonacci numbers:

```
def fibs():
    prev1 = 1
    prev2 = 2
    yield prev1
    yield prev2
    while True:
            prev1 += prev2
            prev2 += prev1
            yield prev1
            yield prev2
```

And then you can use list comprehension to map each of the fibonacci numbers `fib` to `l[fib - 1]`:

```
import itertools
result = [l[fib - 1] for fib in itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x <= len(l), fibs())]
```